# How to loop through different ranges in Java?

Tags: java, loops, logic

I have 2 arrays that contain starting and ending ranges.

```
int[] start = {1, 3, 4};
int[] end = {6, 10, 5};
```

Now, I want to loop through their ranges in such a way that all the values of the array must be covered. For example:

```
if(i==0) start = 1, end=6
we should take values 1...3 because 4..6 will be covered in next step
if(i==1) start = 3 end = 10
we should take value from 6...10 because 4 and 5 is covered in next range
if(i==2) start=4 end = 5
we should take value 4,5 which will complete the whole range
```

As you can see from the above example, we have covered all the values of the array while also covering the range which is ***1...10*** in this case.

So, any idea how can I implement it?

Comment: Can you explain the rules a little more? Why don't you do range 1 completely, ignore values 3-6 in range 2 and ignore range 3 completely? How would the situation be if I'd swap ranges 1 and 3 in your example?

Comment: @Thomas It was a competitive programming question that has this rule we have to cover all the values in the array and also the range. Suppose if there are 4 values in start and end start = {1, 4, 8, 12} and end = {5, 9, 14, 15}. 
So, we should cover range 1..3 when i=0 
when i=1 we should cover range 4..7
when i=2 we should cover 8...11 
and when i=3 we should cover 12...15 
In this way, we are covering the range i.e. 1...15, and also taking values from each range of start and end array

Comment: So we cannot ignore any range because it is fully covered by any of the others? Do we have an upper limit on the ranges or could it by theoretically [Integer.MIN, Integer.MAX]?

Comment: @Thomas the upper limit is 10^5.

Comment: are "competitive programming question" meant to be solved using ANY online help?? And you still have not explained the rules, just another example (is good, but not sufficient)

Comment: One more question: do the values that are considered in each loop have to be consecutive? What I mean is this: in your example numbers 3 and 6 would be covered by either range 1 or range 2, i.e. when looping could the values be [1,2,3,6], [7,8,9,10], [4,5]? or would number 6 have to be part of range 2 because it would be consecutive?

Comment: As I understand, the whole range **¹**, defined by smallest value in 1st array and largest value in 2nd array must be covered only once; later ranges have "priority", that is, their values should not be covered before || **1** or is it all ranges, eventually with gaps (uncovered values) in-between, must be covered only once

Comment: Yes, @Thomas the values have to be consecutive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'd do is spell out the ranges of each step, then going backwards,
remove the later ranges from earlier ranges and remove the beginning of the range if it is non consecutive.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class ExclusionForwardBack {

    static void compute(int[] start, int[] end, List<List<Integer>> results) {
        for (int i = 0; i < start.length; i++) {
            List<Integer> step = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = start[i]; j <= end[i]; j++) {
                step.add(j);
            }
            results.add(step);
        }
        
        for (int i = start.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
                results.get(j).removeAll(results.get(i + 1));
            }
            
            List<Integer> current = results.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < current.size() - 1; j++) {
                if (current.get(j) + 1 != current.get(j + 1)) {
                    for (int k = j; k >= 0; k--) {
                        current.remove(k);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    static void print(List<List<Integer>> results) {
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Step " + i);
            for (int j : results.get(i)) {
                System.out.println("  " + j);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] start1 = {1, 3, 4};
        int[] end1 = {6, 10, 5};

        List<List<Integer>> results1 = new ArrayList<>();
        
        compute(start1, end1, results1);
        print(results1);

        int[] start2 = {1, 4, 8, 12};
        int[] end2 = {5, 9, 14, 15};

        System.out.println("=======================");
        
        List<List<Integer>> results2 = new ArrayList<>();
        
        compute(start2, end2, results2);
        print(results2);

        System.out.println("=======================");

        int[] start3 = {1, 3, 5};
        int[] end3 = {6, 10, 6};

        List<List<Integer>> results3 = new ArrayList<>();
        
        compute(start3, end3, results3);
        print(results3);    
    }
}
```

For your two examples, this prints:

```
Step 0
  1
  2
  3
Step 1
  6
  7
  8
  9
  10
Step 2
  4
  5
=======================
Step 0
  1
  2
  3
Step 1
  4
  5
  6
  7
Step 2
  8
  9
  10
  11
Step 3
  12
  13
  14
  15
=======================
Step 0
  1
  2
  3
  4
Step 1
  7
  8
  9
  10
Step 2
  5
  6
```

Comment: if you add 3 in step 1 then the range is not consecutive.

Comment: Please update the question pointing this requirement out. I'll will update my answer shortly.

Comment: Thanks, @akarnakd, just wanted to know what is the use of the current ArrayList when the result ArrayList is also giving the same answer?

Comment: You mean `List<Integer> current = results.get(i);`? It's more concise as I'd have to index into `results` later at multiple use sites otherwise.